# Transpose and change position in data set in (Python 3 and Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to switch the cell positions of large data set by using pandas 
as picture shows

[snapshot of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsn7s.jpg)

the data as follow at csv file:

```
Trace  event
1         Triage
1         Register
1         Check
1         X-Ray
1         Visit
1         Check
1         Final Visit
1         Check
1         Prepare
10        Triage
10        Register
10        Visit
10        Check
10        X-Ray
10        Check
10        Final Visit
10        Prepare
10        Check
..         .
..         .
..         .
..         .
```

and, I want them like this format

```
trace     event
1         Triage  Register  Check  X-Ray  Visit  Check  Final Visit  Check  Prepare
10        Triage  Register  Visit  Check  X-Ray  Check  Final Visit  Prepare  Check
..        ..      ..        ..     ..     ..     ..    ..          ..
```

and so on 
Thus, if any one has suggestion as function or for loop I will appreciated.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["events"]=df.groupby("trace")["event"].cumcount().add(1)
df=df.pivot(index="trace", columns="events", values="event")
df.columns=[f"event{col}" for col in df.columns]
```

It will put events into consecutive columns `event1, event2, event3, ...`

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz Skibinski for your help. Yes, it helps.
However, I want to store every event in separate cell. When I applied the code it store the whole events in one cell. Thanks

 `@Grzegorz Skibinski`

Comment: Thank you so much @Grzegorz Skibinski
Yes, it resolve the issue